# sed : Save output and replace

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I have a script that contains a few variables. One of them is some proprietary path **MYPATH**.
I want to save the output of **MYPATH** and then replace another variable **SOME_OTHER_PATH** with the same value.

**Current entry in myfile.sh**

```
MYPATH="/opt/local/custom/myfiles"
SOME_OTHER_PATH=""
```

**Output that I want**

```
MYPATH="/opt/local/custom/myfiles"
SOME_OTHER_PATH="/opt/local/custom/myfiles"
```

The script that I wrote does this

```
mylocalpath=`sed -n /^MYPATH/p' myfile.sh | sed -e 's/MYPATH/'`
sed -i -e "s/^SOME_OTHER_PATH/${mylocalpath}" myfile.sh
```

There are two problems here

1. Since `${mylocalpath}` contains "/", sed tries to evaluate these and throws an exception
2. I would like to bundle the entire script in a sed file (instead of running sed twice) and execute it as

   ```
   sed -f sed_file myfile.sh
   ```

Comment: For problem #1, see [this answer regarding escaping characters for sed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29613573/2877364)

Answer (score 2):

While I'm sure that this is possible with sed, I would recommend using awk:

```
awk -F'"' '/^MYPATH=/ { path = $2 } /^SOME_OTHER_PATH=/ { $0 = $1 path "\"" } 1' file
```

Save the path to a variable when the line starts with `MYPATH` and use it when the line starts with `SOME_OTHER_PATH`. The `1` at the end is the shortest *true* condition and `{ print }` is the default action, so every line is printed.

To perform an "in-place" edit, just use a temp file:

```
awk ... file > tmp && mv tmp file
```